# Getting a Tree Effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
$('.children a:first').css({'top':'0px','left':'100px'});
$('.children a:eq(1)').css({'top':'20px','left':'120px'});
$('.children a:eq(2)').css({'top':'40px','left':'140px'});
$('.children a:last').css({'top':'60px','left':'160px'});
```

Is it possible to change this into a function and specify the offset? Trying to figure out if i can do something that will loop through each "a" element under .children and double the top and left properties.

Comment: Can't you just use nested `ul`s to achieve a tree structure? http://jsfiddle.net/7PXBD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WUMtp/

```
$('.children a').each(function(i){
    $(this).css({top: i*20, left: i*20 + 100});
});
```

The only trick here is the `i` that we pass into the anonymous function inside `.each()`. `i` will start out as 0, and increase by 1 every time the `.each()` loop begins another iteration. From there, it's just basic math.